# Saving/Applying Gnome Settings not working

Tags: 12.04, gnome, settings

I am unable to change any settings on my Gnome setup, such as favorites in Unity, adding extensions in Gnome Shell, etc.. It appears that the computer just ignores any settings.

In Gnome Shell, I can apply settings, but they don't do anything and the next time I open 'gnome-tweak-tool', the setting I just changed looks like I didn't change anything. As for Unity, if I add an icon to 'stay in the launcher', it does have an effect...until I log off and then it's as if I never changed a setting.

I've searched all over and nothing seems to help.

Install Path:

- Ubuntu 12.04 Beta 2 -> Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I've tried:

- Deleting my Gnome settings
- New User (it happens the same in the new user)
- CHOWNing the home dir recursively to the appropriate user.
- CHMODing the home dir to 0777.

Comment: This unanswered question is about 12.04 which is EOL and OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years. VTC as `not reproducible`.